# Replacing irregular sink and tap

Tags: sink

I would like to replace with a rectangular single (or double) sink and new tap. Would the rectangular part be cut out of the top left?

We like something like this, a clean and deep single rectangular sink.

https://www.appliancesonline.com.au/product/oliveri-ap1491-apollo-sink

What do we do about the space that rotates around to the left?

Any perspective about how to work with what we have would be useful

Photos of space below

[image]

[image]

Comment: The only way is to replace or rebuild the counter top in that area. You'll have to revise to ask something more specific, as your question is broad and design-oriented now, making it off topic.

Comment: That counter top appears to be _very_ shallow (from edge to wall). You may have difficulty finding a "regular" sink & faucet that will install into this small space. Be sure to do your research _before_ tearing out the old one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Countertops are custom cut for the space and the sink.  The space on the left where you currently have a drain pan will either be cut out (no countertop underneath) or ruined by glue and mismatching discoloration.

You will need a new countertop.  Go to a kitchen design store, which could be a hardware superstore with a kitchen department.   Choose a countertop and a sink.  They'll come measure your kitchen, cut the counter to fit the space and cut the opening for your chosen sink.  They will install it too, if you want.

Comment: Thank you. Would replacing the tap in the interim be a straightforward job, or could there be potential complications?

Comment: @Vincent there are _always_ potential complications. You should post that as a whole new question, including the diameter of the hole that the tap installs through. Single hole faucets are plentiful, however, this appears to be somewhat unusual and _might_ have a smaller diameter hole, requiring a special faucet.

Comment: Why would you *replace* the tap on a sink you are about to replace?  If it's dripping, just fix it.  Anyway, yes, to replace that tap unless you are very exprienced you'll need to remove all the drain pipes so that you can crawl back and have access to the nuts and hoses going up into the tap behind the sink.   An experienced plumber could do this blind just by reaching under but you won't be able to do that.  And there is always a decent chance that installing a new tap will necessitate installing new shutoff valves under the sink.  That would be a complication.

Comment: I think the only problem with the current arrangement is that only one person can be at the sink at one time and changing persons would involve coordination. The smaller upper sink would be good for rinsing vegetables and letting them drain. I would try to live with the current sink and carefully consider how the whole kitchen could be organized before tearing out the corner sink.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get a lot of ideas, just type in on your computers search bar or google "corner kitchen sinks". There you will find the names of suppliers of almost anything you can imagine. There are companies like Elkay, Strickley, Dayton, and others. You could also go to the Home Depot or Lowes in your area to get ideas on design, construction, and sizes,  and they can provide you  with guaranteed installation.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am looking to replace the corner kitchen sink with a rectangular one though....